# Converting dimension feature class into standard feature class using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, convert, dimensions

I have found very little information regarding if it is possible to convert a dimension feature class into a standard feature class. This would hypothetically be done in an SDE environment. Our theory is that while dimension features are created, drawn, and displayed using a particular style, it should somehow be possible to extract the features and its attributes and store them into a standard feature class. The features still have vertices, points, or geometry. So extraction should be possible.

How can I do this using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting on a file geodatabase first?

Comment: We have SDE archives that are generated overnight, every night. They are outputted to a file geodatabase. We could attempt a test on one of those. However, I don't see any known options in a file geodatabase to convert or copy a dimension feature class to a standard one.